# error en conversion de tipos en un sprintf

Tags: c++

Al pasar a una variable char la estructura pAdapter me da este error:

*Advertencia    C6284   Objeto pasado como *Param*(3) cuando la cadena es necesaria para llamar a 'sprintf'. Tipo real: 'IP_ADDRESS_STRING'.*

Esto me pasa con Visual Studio, pero en Code blocks lo marca como advertencia, pero compila y funciona

```
if ((dwRetVal = GetAdaptersInfo(pAdapterInfo, &ulOutBufLen)) == NO_ERROR)
{
    char cIP[20];
    pAdapter = pAdapterInfo;

    sprintf(cIP, " %s", pAdapter->GatewayList.IpAddress);
    string tmpStr(cIP);
    size_t found = tmpStr.rfind('.');// Busca el ultimo grupo de IP al llegar al primer punto desde la derecha
    tmpStr.replace(10, 3, "255"); //sustituye el último grupo de la IP por 255
    return tmpStr.data();
}
```

Agradezco vuestra ayuda y sugerencias

Answer (score 0):

El compilador da error porque `IpAddress` es un [struct](https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.10240.0/um/IPTypes.h#L67), no una cadena de caracteres. Esta tiene una propiedad [`String`](https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.10240.0/um/IPTypes.h#L68) que sí es un arreglo de caracteres.

Así no debería haber problema:

```
sprintf(cIP, " %s", pAdapter->GatewayList.IpAddress.String);
```

---

Por cierto, si `tmpStr` es un [`string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) de la librería estándar, no hace falta que uses `sprintf`, puedes simplemente asignarlo:

```
string tmpStr = pAdapter->GatewayList.IpAddress.String;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahora ya compila

Me estaba "mareando" el hecho que Codeblocks lo mostrara como una advertencia y compilara, además el código funciona , pero al parecer Visual Studio es más estricto y no había manera.

Como se suele decir, "No te acostarás sin aprender una cosa más"

Muchas gracias Mateo por tu aclaración.

Comment: Recuerda que esto no es un foro. Por lo tanto la zona de respuestas está reservada para publicaciones que propongan alguna solución y/o explicación. Esta podría ser un comentario. Por cierto, si una respuesta te sirvió, aceptala y en lugar de decir gracias vota la publicación.

Comment: El sitio cuenta con un filtro. De modo que si varias de tus publicaciones son reportadas o reciben muchos votos negativos, no podrás hacer más preguntas o respuestas y los mods tampoco podrán ayudarte. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans